# How do you get BeginForm to use a standard accept-charset by default?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, webforms

I have a website I manage that has a lot of content.  Since we do have to deal with international characters, I want all my forms to have the `accept-charset="utf-8"` attribute.  Right now I have to remember, and have my team remember to set that explicitly on every form in our website:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { accept_charset = "utf-8" })) {
  <!-- content of form -->
}
```

I want to be able to configure the whole site to put that in by default.  In short I want this code:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
  <!-- content of form -->
}
```

to generate this HTML:

```
<form action="/Teaching/Edit/2522" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
   <!-- content of form -->
</form>
```

I haven't been able to find anything to let me do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a helper class that contains static mvcHtmlString methods. Within this, create a 'beginDefaultForm' method to return a BeginForm statement containing your default options:

FormHelper:

```
public static class FormHelper
{
    public static MvcForm BeginDefaultForm(this HtmlHelper helper)
    {
        return helper.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", 
               FormMethod.Post, new { accept_charset = "utf-8" });
    }
}
```

View:

```
// reference the form helper namespace
@using FormHelperNamespace

// call beginDefaultForm
@Html.BeginDefaultForm()
```

You may need to play around with the actionName / controllerName to get the desired route.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'll try this out.  BTW, passing in `null`,`null` for the action/controller preserves the default behavior for BeginForm (i.e. the same action name and controller when the call was invoked.